# Is it possible to call a function on page_load event of pages that inherit from a specific Page subclass in asp.net WebFroms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to execute a function on `Page_load` event of every `System.Web.UI.Page` from which derives my own `CustomPage` class (which obviously inherits from `Page` class as well)

what I have done so far it that I created `CustomPage` class like this:

```
public class CustomPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected virtual void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CallTOTheDesiredFunction();  //this is the call to the function I want
    }
}
```

And in the derived `Page` classes I am doing this:

```
public class DerivedPage : CustomPage
{
    protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Page_Load(sender, e);
        //the rest of the page load event which executes from here on
    }
}
```

As it is obvious, this approach is working but it is not the best solution since I have to call `base.Page_Load(sender, e)` on every derived page.

Is there a better solution to what I am trying to achieve?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is better to override the `Onload` method rather than relying on deriving classes to call the base method.

You can still hook on the Load event in every page, but use the method in the base class.

```
public class CustomPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        CallTOTheDesiredFunction();  //this is the call to the function I want

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```